# How can I avoid multiple database connections?

Tags: php, pdo

I've moved to PDO and written a small function for all my queries (`SELECT/DELETE/INSERT/UPDATE`):

```
function pdo_query($query, $parameter)
{

    try {
        $db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=...","root","");
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die("DB-Error!");
    }
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($parameter);
    if (substr($query,0,6)=="SELECT") {
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } else {
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }

}
```

I'm using this function several times on some pages and so it produces multiple db connects/objects.

Is it possible to put the connection outside the query-function?

I thought this could work but it doesn't:

```
global $db;

try {
    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=...","root","");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("DB-Error!");
}

function pdo_query($query, $parameter)
{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($parameter);
    if (substr($query,0,6)=="SELECT") {
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } else {
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: global $db should also be defined in your function.

Comment: "I thought this could work but it doesn't" - please describe what happened, i.e. effect or error msg.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `global $db;` inside your function, too.  But when you start doing stuff like that, ask yourself, *"why am I not writing OO code"*?  Write a class, define `$db` as a static member of that class, and initialize it once in the constructor.

Better still, do that in a base class, then extend that class for various tables you need to query.  You'll be on your way...

Answer (score 0):

The `global` keyword is used at a function level, and tells the function to find and use a variable from the global scope. To make this work, do:

```
function pdo_query($query, $parameter)
{
    global $db;
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    ...
```

and eliminate the initial global declaration, as it is no longer needed:

```
global $db;
```

Finally, consider encapsulating all of this in a class for true object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use global. Regardless of whether or not your function is a class method or just a function, it can accept the database connection as an argument. So you can create the connection once, and pass it to whichever function needs it.

```
function pdo_query ($connection, $query, $parameter) {
    $stmt = $connection->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($parameter);
    if (substr($query, 0, 6) == "SELECT") {
        return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } else {
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }
}

try {
    $db=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=...","root","");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("DB-Error!");
}

$result = pdo_query($db, $the_query, $the_params);
```

Answer (score 0):

To the same concerns, I chose following solution:
- create a "Dbwrapper" class having a pdo DB as a member.
- constructor initializes members with useful info (`$this->host`, `->user`, `->password`, `->db` and so on) and sets a boolean variable `$this->isconnected` to false. The constructor does NOT open the connection(*).
- `connect()` method checks the value of `$this->isconnected` : if not connected, actually opens the connection (instantiates pdo member) and, if successful, sets `$this->isconnected` to true
- query methods all begin with a call to `connect()`, which simply does... nothing if already connected, and connects otherwise.

So I now just have to instantiate a new Dbwrapper object, and call its query methods each time I have a query to execute, without ever bothering with opening the DB, it's done transparently and only if needed.

Note that I chose to define a wrapper class around a pdo object. You could also consider deriving your own class from pdo to add this functionality.

(*) as the constructor just does a few variable initialisations and doesn't open any connection, I usually instantiate it once for all in an init.php file (amongst other website-wide variable definitions) which is included in every script of the site.